# OpenGL Shading Language basic types

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to run my shaders on an Intel card. I found that samplers types cannot be declared as structure fields... It was disappointing.

My shaders, on NVIDIA platforms, compile and run fine, with samplers arrays and struct with sampler fields. I know that NVIDIA platform is more permissive than others, w.t.r. the GLSL syntax, but I think that sampler types should be allowed in structures and arrays.

But, after having read [this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Type) page, I get more confused. In particoular, I have found interesting the following quotes:

> Arrays of sampler types are special. Under GLSL version 3.30, sampler
> arrays can be declared
>
> Structs cannot contain variables of sampler types.

So, I have investigate on GLSL specifications, and while searching I found that the sampler type in a basic one (para 4.1), the array can be composed by basic types (para ), and the same for structure member declarations (para 4.1.9). Am I misinterpreting the specification, or the Intel driver is too *"strict"*?

Someone could point a spot on this question? The final question should be *"Sampler types are considered a basic one?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What part of this is unclear?

Samplers are basic types. Basic types can be in arrays. And samplers:

> They can only be declared as function parameters or uniform variables (see section 4.3.5 “Uniform” ).

Fields in a struct are neither function parameters nor uniform variables. The struct itself can later be declared as a uniform, but the member declaration *isn't* a uniform yet. Therefore, it is illegal to declare a sampler within a struct.

It is best to not think of samplers and other opaque types as types, but instead as placeholders for special constructs (like textures and such).

Comment: Now I understand the structure question (indeed NVIDIA is permissive on this, while Intel follows the specs). Furthermore, the linked wiki page is wrong about samplers arrays, since they should be available from 1.20, isn't?

Comment: @Luca: The fact that sampler arrays can be declared in GLSL 3.30 does not preclude them from being declared in prior versions.